# Cannot disable Spring Cloud Config via spring.cloud.config.enabled:false

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix, spring-cloud, hystrix

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not using Spring Cloud Config directly, it is transitive via Spring Cloud Hystrix starter.

When only using `@EnableHystrix`, Spring Cloud also tries to locate a configuration server, expectedly unsuccessfully, since I'm not using one.  The application works just fine, as far as I can tell, but the problem is in the status checks.  Health shows `DOWN` because there is no config server.

Browsing the source of the project, I'd expect `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` to disable this functionality chain, however this is not what I'm seeing.

After upgrading to `1.0.0.RC1` (which adds this property) and using `@EnableCircuitBreaker`:

```
{
    status: "DOWN",
    discovery: {
        status: "DOWN",
        discoveryClient: {
            status: "DOWN",
            error: "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined"
        }
    },
    diskSpace: {
        status: "UP",
        free: 358479622144,
        threshold: 10485760
    },
    hystrix: {
        status: "UP"
    },
    configServer: {
        status: "DOWN",
        error: "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http: //localhost: 8888/bootstrap/default/master":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"
    }
}
```

After checking the configprops endpoint, it *seems* that my properties are being overridden.  Note that the parent has the configClient enabled.

```
parent: {
    configClientProperties: {
        prefix: "spring.cloud.config",
        properties: {
            password: null,
            discovery: {
                enabled: false,
                serviceId: "CONFIGSERVER"
            },
            name: "bootstrap",
            label: "master",
            env: "default",
            uri: "http://localhost:8888",
            enabled: true,
            failFast: false,
            username: null
        }
    }
},
configClientProperties: {
    prefix: "spring.cloud.config",
    properties: {
        password: null,
        discovery: {
            enabled: false,
            serviceId: "CONFIGSERVER"
        },
        name: "bootstrap",
        label: "master",
        env: "default",
        uri: "http://localhost:8888",
        enabled: false,
        failFast: false,
        username: null
    }
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated, if it seems I'm not doing this correctly.

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.0.0.M3 of spring-cloud-starter-parent, which pulls in the same version of spring-cloud-starter-hystrix.  I've updated my question with this information as well, thanks.

Comment: Try RC1 (just released). I think that flag was added (or extended) more recently.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveSyer - I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: @DaveSyer - I've added my findings to the original post rather than the comments. I'm not sure if that change is for better or for worse in my case.  I've also noted some parent properties that may be overriding my config.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The config server is needed during bootstrap, and that's where the parent property sources come from. It looks like all you need to do is move your `spring.cloud.config.enabled` property to bootstrap.yml (or .properties).

Comment: There seems to be some remaining cloud-config bleed over in the `DiscoveryClient`. `ConfigServer` seems to have been resolved, but `DiscoveryClient` is still showing as `DOWN` despite also adding `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: false` to `bootstrap.properties`

Comment: That's the default anyway. And discovery is not connected to config, so I'd say that's another problem (we don't test much yet with different combinations of dependencies). Start a new post here or raise an issue in github for that?

Comment: I'll do that.  I'll mark this answered since it answers the original question.

Comment: Adding of `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` (rather than `spring.config.enabled`) - to `bootstrap.properties` helped to eliminate `Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888`        thanks

Comment: Isn't the property removed now? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes

Answer (score 16):

- You can put a bootstrap properties or yml to your resource direcotry
  or your applications directory and add
  `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`. OR
- You can disable spring cloud config server client by adding an environment variable: `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED=false` OR
- Config server client can be disabled by adding a parameter to your app, if you pass the args to parameters to SpringApplication.run:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
}
```

and start the app by:

```
java -jar yourapplication.jar --spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, I wanted to have the config server disabled (as we do not need it so far) but the property mentioned above is not correct for RC1 at least.

```
spring.cloud.enabled
```

Should be:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried all of the above changes and still config client never stopped somehow.

The only way I was able to disable it by using following exclusion in my project's pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly the sitation. None of the solutions out there work, but this exclusion method doesnt quite feel the best otpion.

Comment: Did you add the spring cloud config properties in the `bootstrap.yaml` file (not the `application.properties`)?

Comment: I managed it with including `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` and commenting out `spring-cloud-starter-config`. No exclude needed. Maybe you can try that too.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the discovery service followup (looks like no other posts on that), setting `spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: false` worked for me, but only if it was set in bootstrap(yml/properties) and if I removed the `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation from my `Application` class.  I guess this means one cannot use that annotation for any service where discovery will not be used at times.

Answer (score 0):

None of those has helped me, I needed to disable spring cloud client bootstrap from server for my integrations tests, so whoever faces the same issue may use what as helped me:

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.class),
})
public class TestApplication {

}
```

and than annotate your tests with:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
class SomeIntegrationTest {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've this enabled then first delete it :

```
config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
```

after that use `spring.cloud.config.enabled` in your application.yml.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Spring Cloud Vault and wanted to do this programmatically because I can apply a `@ConditionalOnProperty` to this class. This will apply the config during bootstrap.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DisabledVaultConfig implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        log.info("Disabling Vault");

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

        // Set the property to false
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<String>("disabledVaultConfig") {
                    @Override
                    public Object getProperty(String name) {
                        if ("spring.cloud.vault.enabled".equals(name)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Create a file named `spring.factories` in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/` directory of your project and add the below within the file:

[image]

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=com.example.DisabledVaultConfig
```