# How to start jhipster microservice application without tomcat

Tags: java, jhipster

I have created a jhipster (v3.4.0) microservice app and wanted to deploy it on production but not on a tomcat instance. I've configure it not to require jhipster-registry nor jhipster-console for log forwarding. So what I want to achieve is to run it as a java app/jar.

Here are my logs from running it with dev profile:

```
hostname:myapp edmond$ ./mvnw 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Myapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ myapp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 43 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ myapp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.6.201602180812:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ myapp ---
[INFO] surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:/Users/edmond/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.6.201602180812/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.6.201602180812-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/edmond/workspace/myapp/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ myapp ---
[WARNING] diagnostic: warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[mapstruct.defaultComponentModel, mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp]'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 161 source files to /Users/edmond/workspace/myapp/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /Users/edmond/workspace/myapp/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ myapp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ myapp ---
2016-09-17 13:02:17.453 DEBUG 3087 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property

        ██  ██    ██  ████████  ███████    ██████  ████████  ████████  ███████
        ██  ██    ██     ██     ██    ██  ██          ██     ██        ██    ██
        ██  ████████     ██     ███████    █████      ██     ██████    ███████
  ██    ██  ██    ██     ██     ██             ██     ██     ██        ██   ██
   ██████   ██    ██  ████████  ██        ██████      ██     ████████  ██    ██

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2016-09-17 13:02:19.150  WARN 3087 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/myapp/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-09-17 13:02:19.152  INFO 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : The following profiles are active: dev
2016-09-17 13:02:24.969  WARN 3087 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-09-17 13:02:26.032 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.AsyncConfiguration        : Creating Async Task Executor
2016-09-17 13:02:27.293 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Registering JVM gauges
2016-09-17 13:02:27.314 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2016-09-17 13:02:30.606  INFO 3087 --- [ost-startStop-1] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
2016-09-17 13:02:31.162 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Configuring Hazelcast
2016-09-17 13:02:31.206 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Configuring Hazelcast clustering for instanceId: myapp
2016-09-17 13:02:31.209 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Application is running with the "dev" profile, Hazelcast cluster will only work with localhost instances
2016-09-17 13:02:31.341  INFO 3087 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:13782, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=13782], bind any local is true
2016-09-17 13:02:31.716  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService       : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Backpressure is disabled
2016-09-17 13:02:31.746  INFO 3087 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.c.ClassicOperationExecutor     : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Starting with 2 generic operation threads and 2 partition operation threads.
2016-09-17 13:02:32.375  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Hazelcast 3.6.1 (20160228 - d0d2a77) starting at Address[127.0.0.1]:13782
2016-09-17 13:02:32.376  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2016-09-17 13:02:32.376  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2016-09-17 13:02:32.386  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Creating TcpIpJoiner
2016-09-17 13:02:32.395  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[127.0.0.1]:13782 is STARTING
2016-09-17 13:02:32.563  INFO 3087 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2016-09-17 13:02:32.566 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] InputThreads selectNow enabled=false
2016-09-17 13:02:32.567 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] c.h.n.t.n.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel    : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] OutputThreads selectNow enabled=false
2016-09-17 13:02:32.585  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner   : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] 


Members [1] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:13782 this
}

2016-09-17 13:02:32.662  INFO 3087 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[127.0.0.1]:13782 is STARTED
2016-09-17 13:02:32.746 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
2016-09-17 13:02:32.754 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.DatabaseConfiguration     : Configuring Datasource
2016-09-17 13:02:32.863 DEBUG 3087 --- [        cached2] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@5268e0755 pairs: {GET /ping?version=3.6.1&m=bf74a0ee-32c7-42f6-9cd5-4bb447422f23&e=false&l=NULL&p=maven&c=672524cf-65e9-4d0a-9bf0-3f8ee7e5b89d&crsz=A&cssz=A&hdgb=0&ccpp=0&cdn=0&cjv=0&cuptm=52&nuptm=51033 HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0}{Host: phonehome.hazelcast.com}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
2016-09-17 13:02:33.107 DEBUG 3087 --- [        cached2] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@1e6bec8f5 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1}{Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 11:04:42 GMT}
2016-09-17 13:02:33.322 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.config.DatabaseConfiguration     : Configuring Liquibase
2016-09-17 13:02:33.346  WARN 3087 --- [ssor-Executor-1] a.p.v.m.c.l.AsyncSpringLiquibase         : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2016-09-17 13:02:36.764  INFO 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.c.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory  : Starting up HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2016-09-17 13:02:38.924 DEBUG 3087 --- [ssor-Executor-1] a.p.v.m.c.l.AsyncSpringLiquibase         : Started Liquibase in 5577 ms
2016-09-17 13:02:45.294 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration    : Starting Swagger
2016-09-17 13:02:45.312 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.m.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration    : Started Swagger in 17 ms
2016-09-17 13:02:47.732  WARN 3087 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-09-17 13:02:47.747  WARN 3087 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-09-17 13:02:50.203  INFO 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : Started MyappApp in 39.89 seconds (JVM running for 68.597)
2016-09-17 13:02:50.220 DEBUG 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : Routing service toward RouterManager
2016-09-17 13:02:50.229  INFO 3087 --- [           main] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : Consumer started!




^C2016-09-17 13:02:59.462  INFO 3087 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Running shutdown hook... Current state: ACTIVE
2016-09-17 13:02:59.462  INFO 3087 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[127.0.0.1]:13782 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2016-09-17 13:02:59.463  WARN 3087 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Terminating forcefully...
2016-09-17 13:02:59.464  INFO 3087 --- [.ShutdownThread] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.6.1] Shutting down connection manager...
2016-09-17 13:02:59.586  INFO 3087 --- [       Thread-6] a.p.v.m.c.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory  : Shutting down HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2016-09-17 13:02:59.607  INFO 3087 --- [       Thread-6] a.p.v.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Closing Cache Manager
hostname:myapp edmond$
```

Here is where I make it ready for production:

```
hostname:myapp edmond$ ./mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Myapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
[INFO] Building war: /Users/edmond/workspace/myapp/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ myapp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.982 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-17T13:03:28+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 66M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
hostname:myapp edmond$
```

Here is where I run it for production:

```
hostname:myapp edmond$ java -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

*** JHIPSTER ***

```
:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2016-09-17 14:04:08.512  WARN 4419 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/myapp/default": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-09-17 14:04:08.520  INFO 4419 --- [           main] a.p.v.myapp.MyappApp   : The following profiles are active: prod
2016-09-17 14:04:15.893  WARN 4419 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-09-17 14:04:25.844 ERROR 4419 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addFilter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Filter;)Ljavax/servlet/FilterRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(FilterRegistrationBean.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2016-09-17 14:04:25.846 ERROR 4419 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:346)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.domain.smth.myapp.MyappApp.main(MyappApp.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2016-09-17 14:04:25.847  WARN 4419 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-09-17 14:04:25.893 ERROR 4419 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.domain.smth.myapp.MyappApp.main(MyappApp.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:346)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.domain.smth.myapp.MyappApp.main(MyappApp.java:76)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:346)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:89)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 25 more
hostname:myapp edmond$
```

**EDIDTED on: 25/11/2016**

- I removed all references of tomcat embedded from pom.xml, because of not need as of my project.
- I removed all references of Servlets/ HTTPServlet.
- I'm running it now with SpringApplication instead of ApplicationContext

Comment: This the default way to run JHipster apps, it works out of the box unless you modified the generated pom.xml and dependencies.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I'm trying to find out what we've might added on pom during development. But from what I checked today even the `./mvnw package -Pdev -DskipTests` and `java -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a closer look at your logs, I think IMHO that your app is trying to get the configuration for your app, i.e. is looking up for http://localhost:8888/myapp/default.

Under the port 8888 is running mostly the [spring clod config service](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) ([here is the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.1.3.RELEASE/)).  Since you don't want to run the registry service check how your microservice is configured, e.g. have a look at the boostrap-[profile].yml in the config folder of your app.

cheers,duderoot

Comment: I did try though to disable spring could config but for some unknown reasons the app was not getting this config. The config that I added was
`spring:\n\tcloud:\n\t\tconfig:\n\t\t\tenabled: false`

Comment: I gues the problem is where you put your config. As specified here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573169/1572439 you need to put your config in the bootstrap config because the config is need it at boot time ;)

Comment: Yes  @duderoot is right, the port 8888 is the default for spring cloud config server but for JHipster it is 8761 (registry) so I suspect that you removed its config from bootstrap.yml and now get the spring boot autoconfiguration for it. Have a look at spring boot and check which condition they use (could be a class, an annotation, a property).

Comment: @duderoot, your answer was helping in removing some of the warning. Thanks.