# Disable spring cloud config client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to disable spring-cloud-config-client for my application. spring-cloud-config-client is present as dependency hence on classpath. It auto-triggers everytime as app starts as expected. My usecase is to control this auto-trigger with a property.

My attempt:

1. This property `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` I have supplied in bootstrap.properties but still not working.
2. I have gone through [Cannot disable Spring Cloud Config via spring.cloud.config.enabled:false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569168/cannot-disable-spring-cloud-config-via-spring-cloud-config-enabledfalse) but did not work
3. Other fallback option is to use `spring.cloud.config.overrideSystemProperties=false` and `spring.cloud.config.overrideNone=true` inorder to use system/local properties.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying ?
2. Where should I look to find why its not working ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to disable it, what's odd for me is the fact that you're using the right property at the right place and it still doesn't work.
Do you have this project in a public repo?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share this project in public. This spring-cloud-config-client is also customised one for my org, but shouldn't make difference since it modifies bootstrap process which should again be dependent on the property. Where else should I look to get to the depth ?

Comment: You can enable debug-mode and see what's happening